# Alt-Tabbing from a stretched game window to a normal window, changes 2nd window's resolution to 1st's. Whose fault: Win OS, Nvidia driver or the Game?

Tags: windows, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

Say I have Nvidia driver set to stretch the lower resolution windows, say 1280x960 of some game, to stretch to full screen, say 1920x1080.

Then, after alt-tabbing from such a game window, all the other windows too, I guess, are receiving a resolution change event, and they are switching to the lower resolution, meaning, they'll start rendering now at 1280x960, from 1920x1080! For example, MS Edge browser windows would behave that way!

Ideally after getting out of the stretched game window, other programs' windows should maintain their resolutions. But they don't!

Who can be at fault here? Is it Nvidia's GPU driver, or the Windows OS, or the Game itself (that perhaps asks/pushes a global res-change, rather than an only for itself local res-change!)? Who is messing up what resolution to keep for which individual windows?

**Update**: I can say it's not the games at fault, because I've tested it with two different titles (CS:GO & GTA-V) by running them at 1280x960, & they both caused the MS Edge window to restore at lower res from FHD!

Also is there a solution, aside from changing window resolutions manually (like applying Restore & then Maximize) per each window, after they start rendering at the wrong lower resolution?

Comment: Side note: By convention 1280x960 is landscape and 960x1280 is portrait. Do you play CS:GO in portrait orientation? I know mobile phones are the reason vertical video shooting is popular, but I never expected this trend to get into PC gaming. Puzzle games maybe, but first person perspective? Please tell me you meant 1280x960.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski But of course! Let me rephrase the question to reflect that the setup is indeed landscape, where it's using either 1920 or 1280 horizontal by 1080 or 960 vertical pixels!

Comment: Faith in humanity restored. :)